# What kind of base64 it is?

Tags: php, md5

So I have a string that is `123456` then I md5 it and now I have hash `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` then I don't know what kind of base64 (this is my thought about base64, mb its not base64 encryption) code put on my hash to it's became `L+PCElCBkZ35CXOOo5cjaP01MFdYW61v7w2eKROSNWg=`

Simplify: `123456` -> md5 -> ???? = `L+PCElCBkZ35CXOOo5cjaP01MFdYW61v7w2eKROSNWg=`

Please help me determinate that kind of encryption.

Comment: I suggest you go back to your place of education and take some courses in what actually a hash is and what encryption is because this is just plain wrong.

Comment: Your forgot: "how BASE64 typically looks like"

Answer (score 4):

First of all:

- hashing is not encryption: `md5` was supposed to be one way; a crypto system (be it as bad as it may be) is supposed to have a encryption and a decryption method that reverses the encryption. This is not and cannot be true for hashing, as the image space is way smaller than the urimage space of a hash function. Btw, finding pre-images for md5 images is computationally feasible nowerdays, e.g. that is not secure hashing.
- encoding is - technically - encryption (like doing nothing at all, `id` is, too), but usually, the word "encryption" is nowerdays understood in a broader range to include a notion of security. Encoding does offer a way back and the "key" is always the same and everybody knows it. "Encryption" can thus be easily reverted. So actually, you are **encoding, not encrypting** using `base64`.

Having confused hashing, encryption and encoding is often a sign that some reading on the topic might be a good call.

Apart from that: what is your actual question? Do you suppose the `md5` hash is only `base64` encoded and you do want us to tell you with which algorithm?

Well, `base64`. There are only so many options.

But if this does not work out, have you considered that some actual encryption happens between the hashing and the base64 encoding?

The results of ciphers are often base64-encoded to be able to send them in text. Hashes are not, usually, because they are guaranteed to contain only printable characters in their (usual) hexadecimal notation.

Problem being: You cannot deduce (given a secure cipher has been used) from the cipher text which encryption algorithm has been used, apart from maybe the block size. So as long as you guess some encryption algorithm with 128 bit block size, your guess is as good as mine, unfortunately.

Comment: Btw, 'encoding' **IS NOT** Encryption. It means "to apply an coding scheme". for example when I record a video stream I encode it to follow the MPEG-2 standard, this is in no way encryption, in order to ba able to play it.

Comment: 'Encryption' only means 'there are ways to convert it back and forth', technically. So encoding (not: compressing with loss as in some video 'encoding') technically is encryption. Just _trivially insecure_. Yet, security is not technically part of the definition of encryption.

Comment: @LvB, encryption is applying the encryption function of a [crypto system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptosystem) - for base64, this system has a trivial set of keys. Still a crypto system, still encryption. For all php coders: **Do not use the base64 crypto system, it is unsafe.**

Comment: Straight from wikipedia "In cryptography, encryption is the process of encoding messages or information in such a way that only authorized parties can read it." [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption. And if we go further back in defenition. to encrypt means 'to encipher' or in other words to apply a cipher to it. Encoding means 'to encode' or to apply a code to it. A code (way of writing something) differs from a cipher both in meaning and in scope. although they 'look' similar.